# How do I reorder/sort Firebase data in React App?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, create-react-app

So I'm flying by the seat of my pants here, and I need help reordering a data set. Here's the base of my react component. This is a personal project that I'm doing to then reuse at work for an actual project. The base of this came from a YouTube series  about React + Firebase: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9iWstfXntcj8f-dFZ4UtlN3

Ideally, I'd like a set of buttons that will sort the data from asc or desc. And maybe dependent on some other things.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ShopList from '../shops/ShopList.js';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { compose } from 'redux';


class Dashboard extends Component {
  reOrder = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("button works!");
  }

  render() {
    const { shops } = this.props;

    return(

      <div className="dashboard container">
      <Helmet>
          <title>Dashboard | Indianapolis Coffee Guide</title>
      </Helmet>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.reOrder}>Reorder</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <ShopList shops={shops} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    shops: state.firestore.ordered.coffeeShops,
    auth: state.firebase.auth
  }
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([
    { collection: 'coffeeShops', orderBy: ['shopName', 'asc']}
  ])
)(Dashboard)
```

The data is being ordered right now at the end with the orderBy, but I need to be able to update that...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it would work, because I have never used `react-redux-firebase`, but it seems to me you could create a redux action that sets the ordering direction in redux store. Like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ShopList from '../shops/ShopList.js';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { compose } from 'redux';


class Dashboard extends Component {
  reOrder = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("button works!");
    const orderDirection = this.props.orderDirection === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    this.props.dispatch(ReOderAction(orderDirection));
  }

  render() {
    const { shops } = this.props;

    return(

      <div className="dashboard container">
      <Helmet>
          <title>Dashboard | Indianapolis Coffee Guide</title>
      </Helmet>
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.reOrder}>Reorder</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <ShopList shops={shops} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    shops: state.firestore.ordered.coffeeShops,
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
    orderDirection: state.anything.orderDirection,
  }
}

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([
    { collection: 'coffeeShops', orderBy: ['shopName', orderDirection]}
  ])
)(Dashboard)
```

Please, let me know if it worked...

Comment: So I changed your const to let and it ran, but it doesn't update the data being presented. I logged the orderDirection after the button was clicked and it changed values like it should have, but the data itself didn't update. Any thoughts?

Also, like I said, I just followed that tutorial. So if know another way (re: better way) you would have gotten the data, I'd be happy to give that a try, too. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I have just updated my answer. You can pass a `prop` (let's say `orderDirection`) on the parent component and change the state of the parent component or you can create a redux action specifically to set this. Like this your component will update for sure.

Comment: It's not building because ReOrderAction is not defined?

Comment: Yes, I know. You need to create a Redux action as I said... do you know how to do it? If you don't why dont you try to pass a prop to <Dashboard /> component from it's parent component?

Comment: Ack, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Maybe, in this case, you should not be trying to use redux. You have to write a bit of boilerplate, it can be a bit tedious. But if you really want to use it, then think about watching some tutorials. A good start would be here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrsle5quS7A&list=PL55RiY5tL51rrC3sh8qLiYHqUV3twEYU_

Comment: Maybe I'll just try writing it all from scratch (and from a different tutorial) to see how that goes. Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200202/discussion-between-pedrosimao-and-scttcrry).